# Video problems with EFI boot on KVM/QEMU

Tags: grub2, uefi, video, kvm-virtualization, qemu

when I boot ubuntu-20.04-legacy-server-amd64.iso on Proxmox 6.1 (uses KVM/QEMU hypervisor) with BIOS=OVMF (UEFI) I get corrupted video after select "Install Ubuntu Server" on Grub.

When I boot ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso - the display works - but I really don't like the new installer (partiion manager still lacks advanced partitioning and others).

I know to edit the boot line on grub (press e) and boot the modified entry (ctrl + x) - but adding `vga=792` and/or `video=vesafb:off,efifb:off` to the linux command line, doesn't helps (same problem).

It looks like something is corrupt - than entering the Grub Shell with F2 and call videoinfo just freeze grub with no resulting output.

I know - someone will ask me, why EFI and why legacy image?! But I don't want discuss this - I just try to broaden my horizons :)

***Has someone the right params to add to the linux command line or a other working solution?***

[image: corrupted boot screen]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after testing around with different kernel options - I found the solution:

I changed the VM video hardware to `VirtIO-GPU`.

Now the ISO boots without modification of the kernel command line.

Comment: Brilliant: I had to add "-vga vmware" to my kvm line.  This is on Debian Bookworm, running a virtual machine based on Debian Trixie.  You saved me (more) hours of searching.